# Testing GAE (java) Cloud Endpoints locally with AJAX

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jquery, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I am making calls to my cloud endpoints class with AJAX like so (I cannot use the javascript client api [because this is for a firefox add-on](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?p=28882&sid=5e2096e56c50696b1bd9b8ba01ea65fe)).

```
var restURL =
    //"https://xxx.appspot.com/_ah/api/yyy/v1/article";
    "http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/yyy/v1/article";

$.ajax({
    url: restURL,
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer "+ oauthParams.access_token}
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(object),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(TAG+className+" successfully saved to server.\ntextStatus: "+textStatus);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.error(TAG+"Failed to save "+className+" to server.\ntextStatus: "+textStatus+"\nerror: "+error);
    }
});
```

Because these are cross origin requests, AJAX sends a "pre-flight" OPTIONS request before posting. This pre-flight test works perfectly when deployed (Status code 200), but it fails (404 Not Found) when testing on the local dev server. When testing from the API Explorer, there is obviously no pre-flight request (it's same origin) and it works.
This method is OAuth protected.

Dan, any thoughts?